# Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteBatch" error in powershell for batch insert

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

I am doing a batch insert with powershell to Azure table. using latest Az modules, not AzureRm.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$table = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name myTable –Context $context)

foreach($item in $items){
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation]$batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey
    $entity.Properties.Add("ID", $id)
    $batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity)
}
if ($batchOperation.Count -ne 0) {
    $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
}
```

But am getting error as:

```
Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteBatch" and the argument count: "1"
```

"ExecuteBatch" is this method only available in the old AzureRm module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteBatch` operation is definitely available.

[image]

I believe you're getting this error is because you're using incorrect namespace. You should be using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` instead of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`.

Please try the following code. I tried it and it works:

```
$storageAccountName = "account-name";
$storageAccountKey = "account-key=="

$context = New-AzStorageContext $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$table = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name myTable –Context $context)

foreach($item in $items){
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation]$batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey
    $entity.Properties.Add("ID", $id)
    $batchOperation.InsertOrReplace($entity)
}
if ($batchOperation.Count -ne 0) {
    $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
}
```